# filter dataframe in pandas by a date column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

The data is in the following link : http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html

I want only the banks which closed in 2017. How can I do it in Pandas ?

```
failed_banks= pd.read_html('http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')
failed_banks[0]
```

What should I do after these lines of code to extract the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would use

```
# assuming pandas successfully parsed this column as datetime object
# and pandas version >= 0.16
failed_banks= pd.read_html('http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')[0]
failed_banks = failed_banks[failed_banks['Closing Date'].dt.year == 2017]
```

But pandas doesn't correctly parses the `Closing Date` as date objects, so we need to parse it ourselves:

```
failed_banks = pd.read_html('http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')[0]

def parse_date_strings(date_str):
    return int(date_str.split(', ')[-1]) == 2017

failed_banks = failed_banks[failed_banks['Closing Date'].apply(parse_date_strings)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply ! But I do not  think it parsed it as datetime object here. Should I use regular expressions here?

Comment: It outputs the following error --- `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values `

Comment: @SmithThapa See the in-line comment in my answer. Pandas apparently didn't parse the `Closing Date` column as date, You'll need to convert it to dates and then use my answer, or parse the date string yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

Extract closing year.

```
# using pd.to_datetime
closing_year = pd.to_datetime(failed_banks[0]['Updated Date']).apply(lambda x: x.year)
# or by splitting the line
closing_year = failed_banks[0]['Updated Date'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', ')[1])
```

And select.

```
failed_banks[0][closing_year=='2017']
```

Comment: DeepSpace's solution worked for me. Your solution is quite similar. Appreciate your help. Thank you :)