# How to filter rows based on days in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a Dataframe in which there two column checkin date & checkout date. Initially those two columns were in string type. I have changed them to date time object and calculate days difference between then using checkout date - checkin date. Now I want to filter rows based on the stay duration. Could any one help me to do that as the difference came in also in datetime object format.
Here is my code so far:

```py
 New_Train['checkin_date']=pd.to_datetime(New_Train['checkin_date']) 
 New_Train['checkout_date']=pd.to_datetime(New_Train['checkout_date']) 

 print(New_Train.info()) 
 #Now, Checking date & checkout date type changed to date time
 New_Train['Checkin_Year'],New_Train['Checkin_Month']= 
 New_Train['checkin_date'].dt.year,New_Train['checkin_date'].dt.month 
 New_Train['Stay_Duration'] = New_Train['checkout_date']- New_Train['checkin_date']
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: New_Train['checkin_date']=pd.to_datetime(New_Train['checkin_date'])
New_Train['checkout_date']=pd.to_datetime(New_Train['checkout_date'])

print(New_Train.info())

""" Now, Checking date & checkout date type changed to date time"""
New_Train['Checkin_Year'],New_Train['Checkin_Month']= New_Train['checkin_date'].dt.year,New_Train['checkin_date'].dt.month
New_Train['Stay_Duration'] = New_Train['checkout_date']- New_Train['checkin_date']

Comment: @AtreyiDatta He meant can you include it in your post with proper formatting and explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter dataframe in pandas by a date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613501/filter-dataframe-in-pandas-by-a-date-column)

Comment: How do you want the difference? In minutes hours or minutes? Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283001/get-total-number-of-hours-from-a-pandas-timedelta